# Is there a function that checks if a variable is a member of a list without unifying it?

Tags: prolog

I want to implement a predicate in my cod that finds all the lists that contain a certain element, in my case, that element is a variable, P3 for example.
The problem is that using the predicate member doesn't work because it keeps unifying the variable with the elements of the list:

`?- member(P3, [P1,P3]). P3 = P1 ; true.`

I want it to return True because P3 is a member of the list and not because P1 is.
Is there a way for me to check if the variable P3 is a member of a list without unifying it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `(==)/2` which does what you require.

> @Term1 == @Term2
> True if Term1 is equivalent to Term2. A variable is only identical  to a
> sharing variable.

```
?- X == Y.
false.

?- X=a, Y=b, X == Y.
false.

?- X=a, Y=a, X == Y.
X = Y, Y = a.
```

So you can implement it as

```
membersame(X, [A|_]) :-
    X == A.
membersame(X, [_|Rest]) :-
    membersame(X, Rest).
```

Or you can also use `member/2` for implicit iteration over the list and use `(==)/2` for restriction (thanks @TA_intern).

```
membersame(X, Xs) :-
    member(Y, Xs), X == Y.
```

Examples:

```
?- membersame(X, [A, B, C, X, a, b, c]).
true ;
false.

?- membersame(X, [A, B, C, a, b, c]).
false.
```

Comment: You could use member/2 for this: `membersame(X, List) :- member(Y, List), X == Y.`

Answer (score 0):

In Prolog, a variable can be unified with a value only once. Consequently, if variable `V` can be unified with `this` and variable `W`can be unified with `that`, then those variables are distinct (otherwise, they are the same variable).

```
samevar(V, W) :- var(V), var(W), not((V=this, W=that)).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- samevar(A,B).
false.

?- samevar(A,A).
true.
```

Using `samevar/2`, we can define the following predicate:

```
varmember(V, [W|_]) :- samevar(V, W).
varmember(V, [_|T]) :- varmember(V, T).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- varmember(a, [V1, a, V3, V4, V5]).
false.

?- varmember(V2, [V1, V3, V4, V5]).
false.

?- varmember(V2, [V1, V2, V3, V4, V5]).
true ;
false.

?- varmember(V2, [V1, V2, V3, V2, V4, V5]).
true ;
true ;
false.

?- varmember(V2, [V1, V2, V3, V2, V4, V2, V5]).
true ;
true ;
true ;
false.

?- varmember(V2, [this, V2, that, V2, V3, V4, V5]).
true ;
true ;
false.
```

Comment: Use equivalence instead of unification ---> `==/2` instead of `=/2`.